# MS EXCEL - Sum Range in table extends instead of populate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

Hope you can help me out here.
I have a simple table in Excel that calculated peoples holidays and absences.
A formula in first row is =SUM(C4:AG4)+(AH4+AI4)*7.5-AK4

PROBLEM:

Now - When I enter a new record the formula is being copied to next row but now changed:

1st row: **=SUM(C4:AG5)**+(AH4+AI4)*7.5-AK4

2nd row: **=SUM(C5:AG6)**+(AH5+AI5)*7.5-AK5

Is there any way to keep the `SUM()` to calculate only the values in current columns.

Expected result:

1st row: **=SUM(C4:AG4)**+(AH4+AI4)*7.5-AK4

2nd row: **=SUM(C5:AG5)**+(AH5+AI5)*7.5-AK5

3rd row: **=SUM(C6:AG6)**+(AH6+AI6)*7.5-AK6

and so on

Note that I'd like to avoid `DIRECT()` and `ROW()` functions. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

EDIT: To be clear - The above is formatted as TABLE not RANGE!
EDIT2: You can download my example here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aWzF7UUaK_-zR5s7_r9V8XxwBkS37T_s

Comment: `SUM(C$4:AG$5)`

Comment: Well, not really.. I keep getting wrong result. This time 2nd Row shows:
=SUM(C$4:AG$5)+(AH5+AI5)*7.5-AK5

Comment: How do you enter new records in your table? your only change is AG4 changing to AG5? in the first row?

Comment: Is the formula within the table? If so where? If not, also, where?

Comment: It's the formula in the table. I add new record by simply writing in the row below the last row and the formulas are being dragged automatically as it' table formatted.
Formula is in the cell B4 - this is the first data row.

Comment: I could not reproduce your error, still works properly on my sheet by following your steps

Comment: I have added the link to download my sheet. Have a look, please.